# How to enable/disable text field on radio button interaction?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

Cannot get this to work. First time using variables passed into functions. Unchecking radio button should disable form field and vice versa. lineid variable distinguishes this radio/text input pair from 10 others.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disablefield(lineid){ 
if (document.getElementById(lineid).checked == true){ 
document.dupedit.lineid.disabled = false;
} else { 
document.dupedit.lineid.disabled = true;
} 
}
</script>
```

Subset of my HTML.

Comment: It's invalid to have an id that starts with an integer. Not sure if it's causing your problem but you might want to look at that.

Comment: @kissmyface - not in HTML5: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: @James Of course you are correct :-) I still do it though out of habit. An id that looks like that isn't (usually) too semantic. I'd probably use the data attribute instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a string into your `disablefield` function, so put the value in quotes when you pass it in. Something like:

`<input onclick="disablefield('2671997')" />`

This is because `document.getElementById` expects a string, not an integer.

Secondly, to enable/disable the field, you need to use `disabled = true;` rather than `= 'disabled'`.

`document.dupedit.lineid` is looking a for a field with name "lineid", which doesn't exist in your form. I would suggest giving the field an `id` and using `document.getElementById` again instead.

If you want to continue using the `name` attribute, you will have to use `document.getElementsByName` instead. This returns an array of matching elements (since multiple elements can share the same name), but if in your code you know that the element in question is the only one with that name, you can do this:

```
document.getElementsByName(lineid)[0].disabled = true;
```

You can see a working version (I think this is how you wanted it anyway) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4P2wR/). And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4P2wR/1/) is a version using `getElementsByName`.

Comment: Thanks - tried that, plus corrected the missing brace per the below but it still doesn't work. Updating code. Sorry - just seen your edits and working through them.

Comment: Hmm, I thought using lineid in the name would replace it with the value that was passed into the function. E.g. `document.dupedit.$lineid` in PHP parlance? Anyway to do that?

Comment: @Dan - See my latest edits. I would definitely suggest using an `id` rather than a `name` though.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing brace on the function:

```
function disablefield(lineid){ 
if (document.getElementById(lineid).checked == true){ 
document.dupedit.lineid='enabled';
}else{ 
document.dupedit.lineid='disabled';
} 
} //<-- here
```

Also, can I suggest you pass `this` to the function. Then you don't have to call `getElementById`

```
<input onclick='disablefield(this)' type.....

function disablefield(obj){ 
    if (obj.checked == true){ 
        document.dupedit.lineid='enabled';
    }else{ 
        document.dupedit.lineid='disabled';
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to re-think the code.

- Don't use ID on the checkbox. Better move that ID to the text field you want to disable/enable and check whether that field is disabled/enabled, not the checkbox itself
- use cleaner JS.

Please, take a look at [**the jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/F8B7s/), I have compiled for you. Does it do what you expect, Dan?